# Unicode character displays different for different users

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding

In a web application, I try to display the Unicode character `0x26d2`. For some reason, the character displays differently for different users (all using Chrome, but with different OSes and different language settings, etc).

I get the following variations:

(1)
[image]

(2)
[image]

(3)
[image]

I'd like to display variant (1) for all users, but can't figure out how to do that (I checked `document.characterSet` which is `UTF-8` for all users). What else could be the reason and how would I go about checking it?

Note, the images were generated by https://www.codetable.net/hex/26d2 (you can try to visit the site yourself to see which version of this character is displayed).

Answer (score 0):

This is true.  Different browsers (etc) have different ways to render characters.  If you insisted on a particular rendering, you will need to use an image.

The third example you have *may* be that the browser (or whatever) does not have that character in its set.

Here's a website that I use:  http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2b26D2

Comment: Is there a way to enforce a certain way of rendering? Is this dependent on the default fonts? Can I provide/specify a font?

Comment: Search the web for 'browser font'.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is about semantic, so character name, and how to interpreted them (combining, accent, breaking words, sorting, etc.), but not about the image (glyph).

Fonts define the design. E.g. Letters `a`, `g`, `e` may have very different images, and so also the symbols.

If you want to define an image, you should specify the font. For html, you should use webfonts, which are defined by you, and not by the browser (and the operating system which run the browser). Look for *web fonts*. https://fonts.google.com/ has a compressive list of fonts which may be used on websites without restriction (and without a fee).

But I warn you: sometime it is good to specify a glyph, especially if you uses for a specific semantic (e.g. on a graph, map, button). But user may expect a different design, so do not overdo it. [Users care much more about consistency in own operating system, and not about consistency of a page on different operating systems/browsers (which probably they will never notice]

Comment: The fonts you link don't have a glyph for `U+26D2` (at least those that I tried). How can I find a font that displays this character (not as square which seems to be the placeholder for not being able to display it)?

Comment: Yeah. It is embarrassing. I'll send a bug report to Google. Noto Math (and other Noto symbol fonts) have such glyph. Also this need a bug report (https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-zsym) See e.g. at https://ctan.org/pkg/notomath?lang=en . To answer you: ask me in few weeks. I'm doing one of such tool [but for now just for the enormous Noto superfamily]